# make ivy not to download sources and license files

Tags: ivy, springsource

Is there a way to configure ivy not to download sources & license files via ivy.xml ?

I'm currently trying to use default ivy repos + spring repository. my ivysettings.xml is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<settings defaultResolver="springSource" />
<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml" />
<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml" />
<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml" />
<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml" />
<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml" />
<resolvers>
    <chain name="springSource">
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
            <ivy
                pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>

        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
            <ivy
                pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>

        <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="shared" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="local" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="main-chain" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="default-chain" m2compatible="true" />
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ivy configurations to specify your desired mapping to the dependencies of your dependencies (Called transitive dependencies):

Don't know what version of spring you're using, this example downloads spring version 3.0:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Compile classpath"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="3.0.0.RELEASE" conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

When referencing a Maven module configurations refer to Maven **scopes**. The default scope in Maven would be **compile**, but you can reference any other public scope.

### Additional note

I'm using a much simpler settings file:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-release"  root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-external" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

In my opinion the [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver is the easiest way to integrate with a remote Maven repository. I think the confusing name is historical, dating back to the original name of the first Maven repository site. You'll need to additionally specify the **m2compatible** attribute, since the original Maven 1 repository format is now almost unknown.

Perhaps one day the ivy developers will create a new "maven" resolver that will make life easier for new users.

Comment: Can you edit your additional note to explain what the ibiblio elements are doing?  I think I have a pretty good idea, but I want to make sure I'm not making bad assumptions.