# ivy com.springsource.repository.bundles.release via Nexus

Tags: ivy, nexus

I have tried to add http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/ as (proxy) remote repository location to our Nexus repository.

The developers are using the following inside they're iv
Inside the ivy-settings.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivysettings>
      <settings defaultResolver="spring.compass.ibiblio" checkUpToDate="true" />
      <resolvers>
            <chain name="spring.compass.ibiblio">
                  <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
                        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                  </url>
                  <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
                        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                  </url>
                  <ibiblio name="compass" m2compatible="true" root="http://repo.compass-project.org" />
                  <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" checkconsistency="false"/>
                  <ibiblio name="javanet" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false"/>
                  <ibiblio name="libraries" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false"/> 
                  <ibiblio name="jboss" root="http://repository.jboss.com/maven2" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false"/>
            </chain>

      </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

However when I try to browse the nexus repository that is set up I cannot see anything under the repository except of

> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
>
> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz.sha1
>
> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz.md5
>
> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
>
> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties.sha1
>
> /.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties.md5

As a result the dependencies cannot be resolved.

Can anyone help?

Randall

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355938/make-ivy-not-to-download-sources-and-license-files)

Basically I'd suggest you use the following settings file to download spring depenencies:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-release"  root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-external" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

These are the Maven repository URLs and the ivy resolver is configured to understand them as Maven2 formatted repositories.

Finally, I think the spring repos are setup to discourage adhoc browsing using web browser.