# Can't get Apache Ivy not to download sources from Spring repository

Tags: ant, repository, ivy

In my project, I use Ivy to resolve dependencies. I use Spring's repository. The problem is that I don't want to download sources and licence/notice files. The settings which produce the problem are as follows:

**ivyconf.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="default" />
<resolvers namespace="apache">
    <chain name="default" returnFirst="true">

    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
        <!--<ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />-->
        <!-- or this one? -->
        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>

    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
        <!--<ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />-->
        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>

    </chain>
</resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///home/nikem/workspace/ark/test.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

<info organisation="com.foo-corp" module="bar" /> 

<configurations>
    <conf name="runtime" description="Modules needed for running the application"/>
</configurations>

<dependencies>

    <dependency org="org.apache.batik" name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg" rev="1.7.0" conf="runtime->runtime">
        <exclude type="src" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="org.apache.batik" name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.bridge" rev="1.7.0" conf="runtime->runtime" />

    <exclude type="src" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    <exclude type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    <exclude type="license" ext="txt" conf="runtime"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="yunowork" default="ivy-runtime" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

<property name="run.lib.dir" value="projlib"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

<taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpath="${lib.dir}/ivy.jar"/>

<target name="clean-lib" description="Removes all libraries">
    <delete dir="${run.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</target>

<target name="ivy-clean-cache" description="Cleans Ivy cache">
    <ivy:cleancache />
</target>

<target name="ivy-runtime">
    <ivy:settings file="ivyconf.xml"/>
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${run.lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>
</target>
</project>
```

In Ivy's cache I see:

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg"/>
    <artifact name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg-sources" type="src" ext="jar"/>
    <artifact name="license" type="license" ext="txt"/>
    <artifact name="notice" type="license" ext="txt"/>
</publications>
```

They are published for all the configs by defaults.

The question is: **Why don't the source and licence files get excluded?**

Comment: I've added logging to MatcherHelper class in Ivy source code and used this updated version. It shows that exclude rule's type and extension are not matched because artifact has "xml" as extension and "ivy" both as name and as type. This is weird.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround to achieve what I want (no sources, no licence/notice files) was to add `type` to `<ivy:retrieve>` task.

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${run.lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" type="jar" />
```

In this case, I don't need any `<exclude>` tags. This, however, doesn't answer the question why exclude didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try (omit the nested exclude in the first dependency):

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency org="org.apache.batik" name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg" rev="1.7.0" conf="runtime->runtime"/
    <dependency org="org.apache.batik" name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.bridge" rev="1.7.0" conf="runtime->runtime" />

    <exclude type="src" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    <exclude type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="runtime"/>
    <exclude type="license" ext="txt" conf="runtime"/>
</dependencies>
```

I have a feeling that the deeply nested exclude may be bugged. See here:

[How to exclude commons logging dependency of spring with ivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364306/how-to-exclude-commons-logging-dependency-of-spring-with-ivy/6367998#6367998)

It's just a hunch, everything seems very fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question on Spring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355938/make-ivy-not-to-download-sources-and-license-files/4361284#4361284).

In brief it amounts to:

1) Clear your ivy cache

2) Change your ivy settings file to use the Spring Maven repositories:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-release"  root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="spring-external" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

3) Try change your configuration mapping from:

```
    <dependency .... conf="runtime->runtime"/>
```

to:

```
    <dependency .... conf="runtime->default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to exclude all of the artifacts you don't want, try explicitly including only the artifacts you do want:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.batik" name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg" rev="1.7.0" conf="runtime->runtime">
    <artifact name="com.springsource.org.apache.batik.dom.svg"/>
</dependency>
```